# I don't see "hello world" showing up in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial book (3rd edition). I've been following all the steps in getting rails set up through cloud9. I installed all the necessary gems and file versions.

I set up my server using this code:

```
~/workspace/hello_app **$ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT**
```

Than I changed the settings in the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 def hello
  render text: "hello, world!"
 end
end
```

And than I changed the route in routes.rb to:

```
  # root 'application#hello'
```

I think I'm following the book exactly but when I go to load the URL it still just shows the default page and none of my changes have gone into effect. I don't see "hello, world!". I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I assume this is a typo on SO, but you have 'ender text' instead of 'render text'

Comment: @brianslattery oops just a typo on here. the code says render.

Comment: @JamieO'Connell If following answer solved your issue than mark it as correct answer, so other can refer it and use to solve their problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to uncomment

```
  # root 'application#hello'
```

So it reads

```
root 'application#hello'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're the best.

Answer (score 2):

Update your `routes.rb`file

```
root  'application#hello'
```